# Windows Phone WebBrowser Styling Support vh

Tags: css, windows-phone, viewport-units

I tried to embed a WebBrowser Control in my apps and open a page with style `font-size: 3vh;`
It seems the webbrowser cannot recognize the tag and the font becomes very big (but it's normal when view in IE in WP)
May I ask if WP webbrowser does not support `vh`?

Also, when we want to set background image for a div, it seems the "cover" style cannot cover the background and the content "overflows" [image]